# Bundle install (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I have just started off using ruby and I'm struggling using bundle.

```
bundle install
```

My error :

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError) 
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 
from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you install bundler? are you on Linux?

Comment: As well as OS, how did you install ruby?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have bundler gem installed,

Try

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You should install bundler first:

```
gem install bundler
```

This needs to be done once after installing ruby.